# Get business name from google place api in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-places-api

I've been looking around the google place api documentation for days but still struggle finding a way to get the exact business name of the location for example MacDonald, Starbucks, etc.

So far I can only get the address by using reverse geocoding api.

Please help, your suggestions will be a big help for me.

Appreciate it!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting a `Place` object currently? [`Place.getName()`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details) should return what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite confusing. How do I getting the Place object in Unity?

Comment: I've not used the API myself, I just poked at the API to see if the thing you're looking for is there (and it is). If you haven't even gotten *that* yet, you've got a more fundamental question that needs to be asked first: "how to use PlacesAPI in Unity?" And that's not one I know how to answer.